# Ordering Legend Items in ComponentOne chart

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, componentone

I'm having a lot of problems reordering the items in the legend of my charts. The thing is I like the order in the chart but I think the order in the legend is wrong and I'd like to reverse that order.

What I tried is:

CType(Me.Content, C1Chart).LegendItems = CType(Me.Content, C1Chart).LegendItems.Reverse()

But it looks like the LegendItems property is readOnly :S

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution of this problem.  Some hours lost trying to find a good solution to fix what I think it's a bug .... and at the end I found an easy way.

In the chart legend you can include this property: `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to reverse the legend by reversing only one `ChartGroup`:

```
C1Chart1.ChartGroups.ChartGroupsCollection(0).LegendReversed = False
C1Chart1.ChartGroups.ChartGroupsCollection(1).LegendReversed = True
```